# Visual Studio registry capture utility has stopped working, error compiling C# project in Windows7

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-7, compiler-errors

[Visual Studio registry capture utility has stopped working.... http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/256/9376236710.png](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/256/9376236710.png)

Windows 7 Shows build error like below everytime I compile my project.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[From Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/466157/registry-capture-utility-win-7-rc1):

1. Locate regcap.exe here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment
2. Right click and select properties.
3. Select Compatibility tab
4. Check box to Run this program in compatibility mode.
5. Select Windows Vista SP2 in the OS drop-down and Run as Administrator.
6. Click Ok and Recompile.

This solution also works on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2008 (32 bit version), where in the 5th step, you just need to select the check box in the last group box "Privilege Level" for "Run this program as an administrator"

Comment: This also works for 64 bit Windows 7 with VS 2010. The path for regcap is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment

Comment: @Guge: Lucky you- not working for me in VS2010 on 64bit Win7 :-(

Comment: @DilbertDave: Which part doesn't work for you? Have you completed all 6 steps in the answer and still got the error message?

Comment: @Guge: Senior moment here, VS2008 (running as Administrator) not VS2010. Above fix does not work for VS2008.

Comment: this is no more working. it was working OK but now my Win7 machine gives "WARNING: Unable to create registration information for file named xx.ocx"

Comment: This fix seems to work for my Visual Studio 2008 on Win7 x64... but I was getting the error in an MSI project, not a C# project.

Comment: I added another reason, after hours of fighting.

Comment: +1 works with Windows 7, VS 2010 when building AddinExpress projects. Many thanks. [rant]Why do we (have to) put up with this sort of witchcraft sh*t?[/rant]

Comment: Confirming that this works with Visual Studio 2008 Professional under Windows 7 Professional 64 bit when compiling a WiX project

Comment: I dont even have a tools folder inside C"\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0.

Answer (score 4):

Another reason [From Add-In-Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/forum/read.php?FID=10&TID=6919):

- Long paths (a buffer overflow?). This was my case: I had *.tlb in a setup project with a long path, I excluded it and it compiled ok.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this build an MSI project using VS 2008 on Windows 7 64 bit. The problem was that an assembly that reference Microsoft.InteropFormTools.tlb and had to be callable from VB 6 through COM. Visual Studio defaulted the type library's Registry property to vsdrfCOMSelfReg. Changing it to vsdrfDoNotRegister solved the problem.

TIP: Pay attention to the Output window during the Build/Rebuild processing. I saw the following warning after I closed RegCap program:

Note: Unable to create registration information for file named 'Microsoft.InteropFormTools.tlb'

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is running into this issue with Visual Studio 2015, the path for regcap is now C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error when I tried to add a class to my project that had previously been compiled as an external DLL that was added as a reference.  I added the class to the project, but forgot to remove the reference to the DLL.   Removing the reference to the external component resolved the problem and this error message no longer occurred.

Answer (score -1):

If your project doesn't require to build in 64bit , you can build it in 32 bit instead.

This works in my case. I build my project VS 2008 and Windows 7-64 bit and have the same error message. I then try to build again in 32-bit and run Visual Studio in Compatibility mode and it works.

1. Run Visual Studio in Compatibility mode for Windows XP:

   - Right click Visual studio icon
   - Select Properties
   - In Compatibility tab, check on Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows 
     XP SP3 and check on Run this program as administrator
2. Go to Configuration manager and Debug your project in X86 mode

Comment: This isn't an answer -- 32-bit vs. 64-bit doesn't have anything to do with the question (or the error message shown).

Comment: @Garga : It _is_ an answer. It may be wrong but no reason to flag it.

Comment: Right now it isn't clear if this "answer" relates to the question at all. So someone *can* compile as 32-bit; what does that have to do with the error received with shahjapan? Put another way, if I thought defragmenting his hard drive would solve this problem, I might post instructions on how to do it. But I'd also make it clear why I thought the two were related. Otherwise it would just seem random.