# Visual Studio has stopped working - on Win 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-7, compiler-errors

I have Win 7 Enterprise. If i open any .cs file on VS 2008/2010 it gives a message " Visual Studio has stopped working" on a dialog box. There are two buttons "Debug" and "close program". Debug button starts devenv in debug mode with assembly code as i do not have the pdb file for the same.

There is another machine with same configuration where the VS 2008/2010 Ultimate works fine. Even reinstalling Win 7 did not solve the problem. Any idea why it is happening?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334005/visual-studio-registry-capture-utility-has-stopped-working-error-compiling-c-pr

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try with some standard VS troubleshooting steps:

- Clean the solution
- Delete / rename all files in your solution created by VS, i.e. all .ncb, .suo, .user files
- Launch Visual Studio with all add-ins disabled: `devenv.exe /SafeMode`
- Reset All Settings: Tools -> Import / Export Settings -> Reset All Settings
- Delete HKCU:\Software\Micosoft\VisualStudio\9.0 and then restart Visual Studio
- Repair the Visual Studio installation through Add/Remove Programs

Comment: I guess the solution file was the culprit. I took a latest .sln file from TFS and it worked fine.

Comment: mine (I think) was the layout, I had the solution explorer hover. thanks for this steps.

Comment: "Reset All Settings" did the trick for me. And this was in VS2012, btw.

Comment: Your settings were reset, but there were some errors.  Oh this is a lot of fun......  I will try to comment back with what worked ( my vs 2012 is working, it is vs 2013 not working  seems like happened after I installed vs 2014 RTP 3 vnext ...

Comment: I did remove VS 2014 vnext (not sure if that caused the problem) and rebooted, but same problem.  Add/Remove Programs - with VS 2013 - Change -  Repair  .  That fixed it.   Worth noting that I zipped the entire solution and it ran fine on another machine, thus for me it was not in the .suo, .sln files.    thx

Comment: reset all settings worked for me as well, I've been having hell with this issue for the last month, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I had the same problem, there is not much help on the Internet. So I thought this could be an easy fix. I re-install Visual Studio Several times but no luck. Finally, I uninstall .NET Framework along with Visual Studio, re-boot and re-install.

It worked fine !!

I thought it might help someone.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2012 Stopped Working

- I couldn't open a project or create a new one without it crashing
- I was getting this error...

  ```
  System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException was unhandled
    Message=No exports were found that match the constraint: 
      ContractName    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.IGlyphService
      RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Language.Intellisense.IGlyphService
    InnerException:
  ```

However, as mentioned above this worked for me:

- Launch Visual Studio with all add-ins disabled:

  ```
  devenv.exe /SafeMode
  ```
- Reset All Settings: `Tools -> Import / Export Settings -> Reset All Settings`

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same problem some time back but was solved when i installed this patch fix.

Check it out here -
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26662.

Comment: Hey its Intellisense patch.. I am facing the problem with VS 2008 also..!

Answer (score 0):

For me ... one of extension I installed earlier is the culprit. That extension is some sort of code reflector. That tool manage to slow down my debugging when i step forward. And make visual studio 2012 constantly crashing. So my advice is be careful what tools and extensions you install... especially those that are not created by Microsoft themselves.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the crash was caused by the parallel project builds. After went to `Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run` and set `maximum number of parallel project builds` to 1, the crash was gone.

Answer (score 0):

1. There could be multiple issues even in the code if the call to an async method an awaiter is missing.
2. If everything seems to correct from code-wise then clean the solution and delete all the obj and bin fill from all project. Start building the solution again.
   This worked multiple times in my scenario.