# Hotkeys no longer work in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

Suddenly none of hotkeys in C# Express work (like F5, F6 etc.). I don't know what I've done, but no doubt its something stupid. Does anyone know how to fixed this?

I have tried the Keyboard settings in Options, but it won;t even let me add hotkeys for some reason, even once I've removed the old ones. So re-adding them does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reset your Visual Studio Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075%28VS.90%29.aspx).
If that doesn't help
[repair your Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983433%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, repairing it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

- Try restarting your computer.
- Have you made any changes recently (Installed a new Add-in or some other software on your PC).
- Do the hot keys work in other applications?  If no then it has nothing to do with VS.
- Did you try a different keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the Visual Studio standard trouble shooting steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856185/visual-studio-has-stopped-working-on-win-7/2856244#2856244). These are for the non-Express-editions, but I guess they will also work for the Express versions. Have a look especially at resetting all settings and check for add-ons.