# Visual Studio Community Keeps Crashing / Stopped Working On Start Up

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Every time I load Visual Studio it keeps crashing / Stopped working. It happened before but I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and still the same problem I use the Visual Studio 2015 and still the same problem , I would look for the log but I can't locate it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to look for answers here:
[Visual Studio 2015 crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021049/visual-studio-2015-crashes) 
[Visual Studio has stopped working - on Win 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856185/visual-studio-has-stopped-working-on-win-7) 
["Visual Studio 2012 has stopped working" when solution is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076487/visual-studio-2012-has-stopped-working-when-solution-is-opened) 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/087f51a7-f3e9-45ea-adac-d603c0537fa6/microsoft-visual-studio-community-2015-has-stopped-working?forum=vssetup

In each page the error `MS Visual Studio *** has stopped working` is mentioned.

Comment: I did Delete HKCU:\Software\Micosoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and now it gives me this error I put it in the answers bit

Comment: I Done everything those links you sent and still nothing

Comment: Yeah Comes up every now and then if it don't it just says it stopped working